# basic time series(ADC) transfer arhitecture with open62541

Tags: open62541

I'm new to OPCUA protocol, and I want to make OPCUA server on device that samples continious analog signal. What is the best OPCUA arhitecture for fast continious sample transfer to client?

Answer (score 0):

I recommend

> OPC UA Pub/Sub architecture : [OPC 10000-14: OPC Unified
>   Architecture](https://reference.opcfoundation.org/v104/Core/docs/Part14/)

Meaning OPC UA over MQTT.

Reason:

1. From a data speed perspective
2. END-TO-END encryption
3. OPC UA object encoding
4. standards-based data connectivity

Ref: [opcfoundation](https://opcconnect.opcfoundation.org/2017/10/should-i-use-opc-ua-mqtt-amqp/), [OPC UA Publish-Subscribe (Pub/Sub) - IoT becomes easier](https://www.unified-automation.com/news/news-details/article/opc-ua-publish-subscribe-pubsub-iot-becomes-easier.html)